# Java class which can contain only objects that implement an interface?

Tags: java, generics

What I need is to define a class that can be typed to hold objects of a specific type.  The held objects need to also have a reference back to the containing class.

I'm not sure if I'm barking up the wrong tree, or if I'm close to a solution other then the Eclipse warning about type safety.

The interface looks like (this seems to be defined correctly):

```
public interface ItemInterface {
    public ItemOwner<? extends ItemInterface> getOwner();
    public void setOwner(ItemOwner<? extends ItemInterface> owner);
}
```

The owner class looks like (this also seems straightforward):

```
public class ItemOwner <T extends ItemInterface> {

    private NavigableSet<T> items = new TreeSet<T>();

    public Set<T> getItems() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(items);
    }   

    public void addItem(T item) {
        // if we are passed a null, throw an ILA error
        if (item == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument was null.");

        // check whether already is a member
        if (items.contains(item))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Already a member.");

        items.add(item);
        item.setOwner(this);
    }

    public void removeNode(T item) {
        // if we are passed a null, throw an ILA error
        if (item == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument was null.");

        // check whether node already is a member
        if (!items.contains(item))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a member.");

        items.remove(item);
    }
}
```

And the items which can be owned looks like:

```
public class Item implements ItemInterface {

    private ItemOwner<? extends ItemInterface> owner;

    public ItemOwner<? extends ItemInterface> getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(ItemOwner<? extends ItemInterface> owner) {
        // if we are passed a null, throw an ILA error
        if (owner== null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument was null.");

        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting in Eclipse is a warning on getOwner() that: "The expression of type ItemOwnerneeds unchecked conversion to conform to ItemOwner".

Comment: I loaded your code in Eclipse Indigo with JDK7 and got no errors after fixing the `return Collections.unmodifiableSet(nodes);` line to reference `items` instead of `nodes`.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I'll take another crack at turning into a working set of AspectJ introduced behavior.  I broke it out to concrete classes because I was having trouble inside of AspectJ.